# Ревью кода. Как можна улучшить этот код?

Tags: javascript, html, css, инспекция-кода

я изучаю front-end разработку 2 .5 месяца, решил перейти на практику и написал todo list за часов 8

1. Напишите, пожалуйста, свое мнение о коде и как его можно улучшить (желательно по html, css тоже, но в приоритете JS)
2. Хочу начать изучение React, уже можно начинать или лучше ещё попрактиковаться на JS?

Ссылка на код: https://codepen.io/domarchuk77/pen/xxRoMBY

```js
class Task {
    constructor(){
        counter++
        this.taskText = document.querySelector(".todo__settings__input").value
        this.task = pattern.cloneNode(true)
        this.taskList = document.querySelector(".todo__list")
        this.taskList.prepend(this.task)
        this.taskName = document.querySelector(".todo__list__item__text")
        this.itemProgress = document.querySelector(".todo__list__item")
        this.taskName.innerHTML = this.taskText
        this.itemProgress.classList.add("in-progress")
        this.taskDelete()
        this.taskComplete()
        this.taskFilter()
        input.value = ""
    }
    taskDelete(){
        this.buttonDelete = document.querySelector(".todo__list__item__buttons__finish")
        this.buttonDelete.addEventListener("click",() => {
            this.task.remove()
            counter--
            console.log(counter)
            if(counter == 0){
                this.filter.disabled = true
                this.filter.value = "all"
            }
        })
    }
    taskComplete(){
        this.buttonComplete = document.querySelector(".todo__list__item__buttons__complete")
        this.buttonComplete.addEventListener("click",() => {
           this.buttonComplete.remove()
           this.itemProgress.classList.add('task-complete')
           this.filterCheckActive()
           if(this.itemProgress.classList.contains('in-progress')){
               this.itemProgress.classList.remove('in-progress')
           }
        })
    }
    taskFilter(){
        this.filter = document.querySelector(".todo__settings__filter")
        this.filter.disabled = false
        this.filter.addEventListener("change",() => {
            if(this.filter.value == "all"){
                this.itemProgress.classList.add('show')
            }else{
                this.itemProgress.classList.remove('hide')
            }
            this.filterCheckActive()
            if(this.filter.value == "complete"){
                this.itemProgress.classList.remove('show')
                this.itemProgress.classList.remove('hide')
                if(this.itemProgress.classList.contains('in-progress')){
                    this.itemProgress.classList.add('hide')
                }else{
                    this.itemProgress.classList.remove('show')
                }
            }
        })
    }
    filterCheckActive(){
        if(this.filter.value == "active"){
            this.itemProgress.classList.remove('show')
            this.itemProgress.classList.remove('hide')
            if(this.itemProgress.classList.contains('task-complete')){
                this.itemProgress.classList.add('hide')
            }else{
                this.itemProgress.classList.remove('show')
            }
        }
    }
    checkText(){

    }
}
let counter = 0
let pattern = document.querySelector(".todo__list__item")
pattern.remove()
let input = document.querySelector(".todo__settings__input")
document.querySelector(".todo__settings__button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!(input.value.length == 0)){
        new Task
    }
})
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

@import url("./reset.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@700&display=swap");
body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#b9deed), to(#efefef));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #b9deed, #efefef);
}

* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

option {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.todo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.todo__title {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.todo__settings {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.todo__settings__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 173px;
  background: #268729b8;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.todo__settings__button:hover {
  background: #29a62e;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.todo__settings__filter {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.todo__list__item {
  margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__button {
  background: #e88931;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__complete {
  background: #268729b8;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__text {
  padding: 5px;
}

.line {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 2px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.line2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.task-complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #063607;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="todo">
    <div class="todo__title">Ed's Todo List </div>
    <div class="todo__settings">
        <input type="text" class="todo__settings__input" />
        <div class="todo__settings__button">
            <div class="line1 line"></div>
            <div class="line2 line"></div>
        </div>
        <select class="todo__settings__filter" disabled>
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="complete">Complete</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="todo__list">
        <div class="todo__list__item">
            <div class="todo__list__item__text"></div>
            <div class="todo__list__item__buttons">
                <div class="todo__list__item__buttons__complete todo__list__item__buttons__button" >
                    <img width="13px" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/50/000000/checkmark.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="todo__list__item__buttons__button todo__list__item__buttons__finish">
                    <img width="13px" src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/50/000000/empty-trash.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не забудьте поменять `<input type="text" class="todo__settings__input"></input>` на `<input type="text" class="todo__settings__input" />`, а то некорректный синтаксис

Answer (score 2):

`constructor(){ counter++` — обращение к внешней переменной, объявление которой потерялось где-то ниже класса. Если счетчик относится непосредственно к классу, почему бы не сделать его свойством этого класса? И в дальнейшем обращаться к нему в виде `Task.counter++;` А если по какой-то причине действительно необходима внешняя переменная, приятнее было бы видеть её объявление еще до класса, чтобы при чтении сразу понять, с чем имеем дело (название ведь может быть менее очевидным, чем просто counter - его придется искать в коде);

---

```
this...
this...
< 2000 years later... >
this...
this...
```

Хорошо бы как-то визуально разделять код на логические блоки, добавляя пробельные строчки) Даже в случае обычного текста: Монолитный блок букв воспринимается труднее, чем мысли, разбитые по абзацам.

---

Названия методов `taskDelete(), taskComplete(), taskFilter()`: Весь класс — это и есть task, поэтому эти приставки можно опустить. Обращение `task.delete()` будет вполне естественной, вместо `task.taskDelete()`

UPD: Как оказывается, они в свою очередь, выполняют не совсем то, о чем говорят их названия. Добавляют обработчики кликов на конкретные кнопки.

Вообще говоря, объявленные в классе `методы()` создаются один раз, в момент создания класса, и доступны для использования у всех объектов, созданных классом (экземпляров). А ваши методы для каждой «задачи» создают новые функции для обработки кликов. В контексте такой программы не серьезно говорить про экономию памяти (+/-1КБ?), но в целом, полезно об этом помнить.

---

`this.buttonComplete.remove()` — удаляется HTML-объект из DOM, но ссылка на него остается в `this.buttonComplete`, из-за чего объект продолжает храниться в памяти. Это тоже полезно держать в уме. Лечится выполнением `delete this.buttonComplete`.

---

`class="todo__list__item__buttons__complete todo__list__item__buttons__button"` — Идея понятна, но с такими классами может быть больно работать в дальнейшем. Будет полезно ознакомиться с похожим стилем именований классов [BEM (Block, Element, Modifier)](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/).

---

Постоянным переключением классов `show / hide` создали себе лишнюю работу. Достаточно всем элементам по умолчанию выдать стили `show`, а если нужно скрыть элемент - включить у него класс `hide`;

---

`this.taskText = document.querySelector(".todo__settings__input").value` — Классу, который создает «Задачу», совсем не объязательно знать, откуда он должен брать данные. Мог бы получить текст и выдать готовый HTML-узел задачи.

---

---

Тут не может быть единственно верного решения, т.к. изначально ООП — способ организации большого кода. А попытки протолкнуть его в программы, состоящие из трех функций, всегда выглядят искусственно (вообще, «todo» хорошо подходит для изучения делегирования событий). Всё же, кое-как можно пробовать.

* HTML не трогал, функционал тоже не менял, работает как у вас, немного другим кодом.

```js
const doc = {
  // Мини-библиотека :) Чтобы много не писать document.querySelector

  first: function (selector, root) {
    return (root || document).querySelector(selector);
  },

};


/***/
class Filter {
  // Класс одноразовый.
  // Это попытка вынести логику фильтрации из Task
  // Можно было бы прописать в виде Task.filter = new (class { ... })();

  constructor() {
    let root = this.root = doc.first(".todo__settings__filter");

    root.addEventListener("change", () => this.update());
  }

  update() {
    if (Task.count == 0) {
      this.root.disabled = true;
      this.root.value = "all";
      return;
    }

    this.root.disabled = false;

    let filterType = this.root.value;
    let list = Task.getList(filterType);

    Task.showOnly(list);
  }

}


class Task {
  static count = 0;
  static list = [];

  static filter = new Filter();

  constructor(text) {
    let root = this.root = this._createTaskNode(text);

    this.btn = {
      complete: doc.first(".todo__list__item__buttons__complete", root),
    };

    /***/
    this._initEventListeners(root);

    Task.list.push(this);
    Task.count++;

    /***/
    this.isComplete = false; // Состояние указывается явно в виде свойства
                             // и больше не привязано к наличию класса в HTML

    Task.filter.update();
  }


  _createTaskNode(text) {    
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = (`
      <div class="todo__list__item in-progress">
        <div class="todo__list__item__text">${ text }</div>
        <div class="todo__list__item__buttons">
          <div class="todo__list__item__buttons__button todo__list__item__buttons__complete">
            <img width="13px" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/50/000000/checkmark.png"/>
          </div>
          <div class="todo__list__item__buttons__button todo__list__item__buttons__finish">
            <img width="13px" src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/50/000000/empty-trash.png"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);

    return div.firstElementChild;
  }

  _initEventListeners(root) {
    let del = doc.first(".todo__list__item__buttons__finish", root);
    del.addEventListener("click", () => this.delete());

    this.btn.complete.addEventListener("click", () => this.complete());
  }


  delete() {
    this.root.remove();

    Task.count--;

    let index = Task.list.indexOf(this);
    Task.list.splice(index, 1);

    Task.filter.update();
  }

  complete() {
    this.btn.complete.remove();
    delete this.btn.complete;

    this.root.classList.remove("in-progress");
    this.root.classList.add("task-complete");

    this.isComplete = true;

    Task.filter.update();
  }


  show() {
    this.root.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  hide() {
    this.root.classList.add("hide");
  }


  /***/
  static getList(type) {
    type = type.trim().toLowerCase();

    switch (type) {
      case "all": return Task.list;
      case "active": return Task.list.filter(e => !e.isComplete);
      case "complete": return Task.list.filter(e => e.isComplete);

      default: throw new Error("Expected: { all | active | complete }, but found: " + type);
    }
  }

  static showOnly(list) {
    Task.list.forEach(e => e.hide());
    list.forEach(e => e.show());
  }
}

/***/
let input = doc.first(".todo__settings__input");
let todo = doc.first(".todo__list");

doc.first(".todo__settings__button").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (!input.value) return;

  let task = new Task(input.value);
  todo.appendChild(task.root); // вставка в HTML специально вынесена из класса.
  // Класс: Создал - выдал. Не важно кому и куда.
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */

audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */

img {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */

figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal; /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
    *height: 13px; /* 3 */
    *width: 13px; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}


::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

@import url("./reset.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@700&display=swap");
body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#b9deed), to(#efefef));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #b9deed, #efefef);
}

* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

option {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.todo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.todo__title {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.todo__settings {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.todo__settings__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 173px;
  background: #268729b8;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.todo__settings__button:hover {
  background: #29a62e;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.todo__settings__filter {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.todo__list__item {
  margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__button {
  background: #e88931;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__complete {
  background: #268729b8;
}

.todo__list__item__buttons__text {
  padding: 5px;
}

.line {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 2px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.line2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.task-complete {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #063607;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <div class="todo__title">Ed's Todo List </div>
  <div class="todo__settings">
    <input type="text" class="todo__settings__input" />
    <div class="todo__settings__button">
      <div class="line1 line"></div>
      <div class="line2 line"></div>
    </div>
    <select class="todo__settings__filter" disabled>
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="active">Active</option>
      <option value="complete">Complete</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="todo__list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: * Ищите `«JavaScript formatter»` для вашего редактора кода. Современные редакторы умеют одной кнопкой выровнять весь код.